# Invalid depfile app\parking_app\.dart_tool\flutter_build\da\kernel_snapshot.d Unhandled exception:

Tags: flutter, firebase

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcWEq.jpg)am following youtube tutorial and when am connecting my application to the flutter i got an error like this.but my other fluuer projects are working perfectly. how do i  resolve this.my another flutter applications are working perfectly.i do all the thing like flutter clean,flutter update etc but error still there.

```
`Invalid depfile: D:\parking app\parking_app\.dart_tool\flutter_build\dfade9d1173caf83ed8977836b6e6d7a\kernel_snapshot.d
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml; message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:732:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:870:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:676:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      starter (package:frontend_server/starter.dart:102:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/x/w/sdk/pkg/frontend_server/bin/frontend_server_starter.dart:13:14)
<asynchronous suspension>

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)